# Como inserir uma imagem do banco mysql numa datatables

Tags: php

estou iniciando na programação PHP e baixei um código fonte para estar aprendendo, e este código apresenta um datatables, no qual pretendo inserir uma imagem na grid que encontra-se no banco de dados mysql. Meu codigo abaixo para quem puder orientar-me, fico grato a todos

```
$dados = array();

while( $row =mysqli_fetch_array($resultados) ) 
{

     $dado = array();

     $Foto = $row["Imagem"];

     $dado[] = "<img src='Fotos/' 
                    $Foto class='img-responsive img-circle'  width=20 height=20/>";

    $dado[] = $row["Id"];
    $dado[] = utf8_encode($row["Descricao"]);

                    $dados[] = $dado;
};
```

Não esta aparecendo a imagem na grid do datatables.

Comment: Uma obs.: vc está colocando a variável `$Foto` (supondo que seja o nome da imagem) fora do `src`.

Comment: Qual o formato da imagem? CLOB?

Comment: Estou usando na tabela o campo Imagem varchar(15), e as imagens possuem extensões .jpg

Comment: Estou guardando na variável foto da tabela apenas o nome da imagem. ex: prod1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar a imagem da base de dados basta apenas gravar o nome, por exemplo "imagem.jpg", para receber a imagem e como todos os outros campo, a única diferença é na chamada que teras de introduzir o caminho onde vai esta guardada a foto.

```
<img src="caminho/nome_guardado_na_bd" class='img-responsive img-circle'  width=20 height=20/>";
```